# How to read NetParameter from H5 trained model in C++ or Python in Caffe library?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I like to load trained binary file and print to a text file.

We can read trained parameter in `C++ from caffemodel normally in binary protobuf format`.

How I did was,

```
net_.reset(new Net<float>(model_file, TEST));
    NetParameter param;

ReadNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie(trained_file_protobuf, &param);
WriteProtoToTextFile(param, "model_protobuf.txt");
```

But some trained model comes as h5 format and how to load the file and print to text file in C++ or Python.

In `net.cpp`, I can't find for h5 format as `ReadNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie`.
`ReadNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie` is for `binary protobuf format`.

How to read NetParameter from trained H5 model and print to text files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`CopyTrainedLayersFromHDF5`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/net.hpp#L116) (a method of `Net`)?
Should be something like:

```
net_.reset(new Net<float>(model_file, TEST));
net_.CopyTrainedLayersFromHDF5(trained_file_h5);
```